# Type of music that resembles Japanese singer MISIA

Tags: live-music, japan, soul

I found this artist through a Square Enix game and loved her ever since. I was wondering if anyone knows her and have any suggestions on the same type of music.

[Example of her music](https://youtu.be/jDnLwMLJT24)

Comment: Are you trying to ID the genre of her music (basically pops, soul, R&B) or are you trying to find similar artists? She has such a wide body of performances, if you haven't you might become more familiar with them first.

Comment: @user3169 Yes I'm look to find similar artist. It's hard to find more work from her because most of the music titles are completely Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not specifically looking for Japanese music, the style of that particular song sounds heavily influenced by American "soft rock" of the 1970's.  You might look up [Karen Carpenter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NzGZORKx9w) (who has a similar vocal register) or [Carole King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqQXvcr9Uag&list=PLG0W27j3Wle3UPTQfPJeys9K2h5q0gUJQ).